# FTP 553 Could not create file (centOS)

Tags: tomcat, file-io, ftp, centos

I installed a tomcat under /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.37
and I'm trying to put my web-project in the webapps/ROOT directory,
but I always get "553 Could not create file." in filezilla

ftpusers

```
# Users that are not allowed to login via ftp
root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
news
uucp
operator
games
nobody
```

user_list

```
#root
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
news
uucp
operator
games
nobody
```

and my vsftpd.conf file

```
# Example config file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
#
# The default compiled in settings are fairly paranoid. This sample file
# loosens things up a bit, to make the ftp daemon more usable.
# Please see vsftpd.conf.5 for all compiled in defaults.
#
# READ THIS: This example file is NOT an exhaustive list of vsftpd options.
# Please read the vsftpd.conf.5 manual page to get a full idea of vsftpd's
# capabilities.
#
# Allow anonymous FTP? (Beware - allowed by default if you comment this out).
anonymous_enable=NO
#
# Uncomment this to allow local users to log in.
local_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this to enable any form of FTP write command.
write_enable=YES
#
# Default umask for local users is 077. You may wish to change this to 022,
# if your users expect that (022 is used by most other ftpd's)
local_umask=022
#
# Uncomment this to allow the anonymous FTP user to upload files. This only
# has an effect if the above global write enable is activated. Also, you will
# obviously need to create a directory writable by the FTP user.
#anon_upload_enable=YES
#
# Uncomment this if you want the anonymous FTP user to be able to create
# new directories.
#anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
#
# Activate directory messages - messages given to remote users when they
# go into a certain directory.
dirmessage_enable=YES
#
# The target log file can be vsftpd_log_file or xferlog_file.
# This depends on setting xferlog_std_format parameter
xferlog_enable=YES
#
# Make sure PORT transfer connections originate from port 20 (ftp-data).
connect_from_port_20=YES
#
# If you want, you can arrange for uploaded anonymous files to be owned by
# a different user. Note! Using "root" for uploaded files is not
# recommended!
#chown_uploads=YES
#chown_username=whoever
#
# The name of log file when xferlog_enable=YES and xferlog_std_format=YES
# WARNING - changing this filename affects /etc/logrotate.d/vsftpd.log
#xferlog_file=/var/log/xferlog
#
# Switches between logging into vsftpd_log_file and xferlog_file files.
# NO writes to vsftpd_log_file, YES to xferlog_file
xferlog_std_format=YES
#
# You may change the default value for timing out an idle session.
#idle_session_timeout=600
#
# You may change the default value for timing out a data connection.
#data_connection_timeout=120
#
# It is recommended that you define on your system a unique user which the
# ftp server can use as a totally isolated and unprivileged user.
#nopriv_user=ftpsecure
#
# Enable this and the server will recognise asynchronous ABOR requests. Not
# recommended for security (the code is non-trivial). Not enabling it,
# however, may confuse older FTP clients.
#async_abor_enable=YES
#
# By default the server will pretend to allow ASCII mode but in fact ignore
# the request. Turn on the below options to have the server actually do ASCII
# mangling on files when in ASCII mode.
# Beware that on some FTP servers, ASCII support allows a denial of service
# attack (DoS) via the command "SIZE /big/file" in ASCII mode. vsftpd
# predicted this attack and has always been safe, reporting the size of the
# raw file.
# ASCII mangling is a horrible feature of the protocol.
ascii_upload_enable=YES
ascii_download_enable=YES
#
# You may fully customise the login banner string:
#ftpd_banner=Welcome to blah FTP service.
#
# You may specify a file of disallowed anonymous e-mail addresses. Apparently
# useful for combatting certain DoS attacks.
#deny_email_enable=YES
# (default follows)
#banned_email_file=/etc/vsftpd/banned_emails
#
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
# (default follows)
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
#
# You may activate the "-R" option to the builtin ls. This is disabled by
# default to avoid remote users being able to cause excessive I/O on large
# sites. However, some broken FTP clients such as "ncftp" and "mirror" assume
# the presence of the "-R" option, so there is a strong case for enabling it.
ls_recurse_enable=YES
#
# When "listen" directive is enabled, vsftpd runs in standalone mode and
# listens on IPv4 sockets. This directive cannot be used in conjunction
# with the listen_ipv6 directive.
listen=YES
#
# This directive enables listening on IPv6 sockets. To listen on IPv4 and IPv6
# sockets, you must run two copies of vsftpd with two configuration files.
# Make sure, that one of the listen options is commented !!
#listen_ipv6=YES

pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
local_root=public_html
use_localtime=YES
```

I read that a lot of people helped:

```
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1
```

but not in my case (do I have to put something in ftp_home?)

my user folder is under "/home/robin/"

Comment: Have  tried  `chown -R ftpuser:ftpgroup /webapps/ROOT` and if folder owned to other grout you can make ftpuser join that group Like `usermod -a -G www-data ftpuser` the add promises to all group `chmod -R g+rwx`

Answer (score 6):

You need to run the following commands to allow in SELinux upload and edit files:

```
setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir on
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run ftp command on Linux, my 553 error is caused by not inputting the path and file name of destination. In ftp command console, if I want upload a file to ftp, I need to input the following command:

```
put /local_path/filename /destination_path/filename
```

If the destination path and filename is not specified, ftp will try to put the file into the same path with the local file, and it may cause 553 error if the ftp account have no permission to write the file in the path on ftp sever.

Answer (score 0):

Check what permission does the ftpuser have over /webapps/ROOT
Change permission using chmod as shown below:

```
chmod 7xx /webapps/ROOT
```

choose value of x as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of different suggestions from a lot of different sites and pages... a combination of the above worked for me...

Running CentOS6 with vsftpd

- open ftp ports in iptables
- add user to the OS (for me I added "ftpuser") -- `adduser ftpuser`
- `chown -R ftpuser:ftpuser /var/ftp`  (the home folder for ftp users)
- `chmod -R 755 /var/ftp`
- set the home folder in vsftpd.conf -- `home_root=/var/ftp`
- in the same file, ensure you have `write_enable=YES`
- change settings in selinux `getsebool -a | grep ftp`  to see settings
- `setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access=1` (thanks to VictorV for this one...no other sites showed this)
- `setsebool -P ftp_home_dir=1`
- restart vsftpd  `service vsftpd restart`
- flush iptables  `iptables -F`

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands:

```
setsebool -P allow_ftpd_full_access on
```

If you give the following error:

```
500 OOPS: vsftpd: refusing to run with writable root inside chroot()
```

Then edit your config file /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf and add this line

```
allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```